# Google AdWords mobile click to call conversion - create button

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile, google-ads-api

I add AdWords conversion click to call button for my mobile website  (create a new button with this code) and customize the CSS to look nice. the problem is I didn't succeed to change the font size and the phone number look too small - I tried to change the font size in the CSS but it's not taking affect on the button phone number.
any suggestion?

thanks a lot.

google click to conversion call code :

```js
/* <![CDATA[ */
goog_snippet_vars = function() {
  var w = window;
  w.google_conversion_id = 9612231162;
  w.google_conversion_label = "BimP321dsUy18QivawygM";
  w.google_remarketing_only = false;
}
// DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW.
goog_report_conversion = function(url) {
  goog_snippet_vars();
  window.google_conversion_format = "3";
  window.google_is_call = true;
  var opt = new Object();
  opt.onload_callback = function() {
    if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
      window.location = url;
    }
  }
  var conv_handler = window['google_trackConversion'];
  if (typeof(conv_handler) == 'function') {
    conv_handler(opt);
  }
}
/* ]]> */
```

```css
*#dm *.dmBody div.u_1693778167 {
  font-size: 26px !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  border-style: solid !important;
  border-width: 2px !important;
  background-color: rgba(0, 118, 163, 1) !important;
  padding-left: 75px !important;
  padding-right: 0px !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-image: url('https://irp-cdn.multiscreensite.com/mobile/phone6-592x39.png') !important;
  background-size: auto !important;
  background-position: top left !important;
  border-color: rgba(0, 118, 163, 1) !important;
  border-radius: 18px !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 18px !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 18px !important;
  margin-left: 15px !important;
  margin-right: 15px !important;
  margin-bottom: 10px !important;
  margin-top: 6px !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Google Code for Call From Mobile Website Conversion Page
    In your html page, add the snippet and call
    goog_report_conversion when someone clicks on the
    phone number link or button. -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js">
</script>
<button onclick="goog_report_conversion('tel:000-000-0000')">Call 000-000-0000</button>
```